# Smarty not displaying array values in tpl file

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I want to create an XML file through smarty template. For this, i am passing an array to the template file. This is the code i am using to generate array and to pass.

```
$correct_answers = explode(",", $answer['answer']);
$smarty->assign('answers', $correct_answers);
```

The array is generated successfully and i checked it by using `print_r()`;  But my problem is, it shows empty in the tpl file. If i check the count, it shows 0. I cannot get the array values. This is the template file code.

```
{assign var = "inc" value="0"}
{section name=answer loop=$answers}
    <simpleChoice identifier="{$answers[answer]}">{$answers[answer]}</simpleChoice>         
    {assign var = "inc" value=$inc+1}
{/section}
```

I don't know where i went wrong.

Array Structure is,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alonso
    [1] => Jenson Button
    [2] => Rubens Barrichello
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : Instead of `section` use `foreach`.

```
{foreach from=$answers item=answer}
    <simpleChoice identifier="{$answer}">{$answer}</simpleChoice>         
    {assign var = "inc" value=$inc+1}
{/foreach}
```

This is similar to `foreach` loop in php.

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach